# Maximal input length/Variable input length for TinyGP

Tags: genetic-programming

i am planning to use tinyGP as a way to train a set of Input variables (Around 400 or so) to a value set before. Is there a maximum size of Input variables? Do i need to specify the same amount of variables each time?

I have a lot of computation power (500 core cluster for a weekend) so any thoughts on what parameters to use for such a large problem?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TinyGP your constant and variable pool share the same space.  The total of these two spaces cannot exceede FSET_START, which is essentially the opcode of your first operator.  By default is 110.  So your 400 is already over this.  This should be just a matter of increasing the opcode of the first instruction up to make enough space.  You will also want to make sure you still have a big enough "constant pool".

You can see this checked with the following line in TinyGP:

```
if (varnumber + randomnumber >= FSET_START ) 
   System.out.println("too many variables and constants");
```

Answer (score 0):

For variable size inputs you could use a hybrid model (Genetic Programming coupled with a Recurrent Neural Network). The technique is called Liquid State Genetic Programming: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221157270_Liquid_State_Genetic_Programming